# laravel query does not return the entire count of the rows of the relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

i have a query that i want to return an object with its relationship, it has a many to one relationship, one order can have more than one drug i wrote a query like this

> $orders = DrugRequest::where('user_id', $user_id)->with(['drugs'])->latest()->get();

this gets the relationship but not the full rows, for example if an order has two drugs it only returns the first drug not both,

this is my relationship

> ```
> public function drugs(){ return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDrug' , 'order_id' , 'id');}
> ```

and this is when i dd($orders)

[image]

for the order object with the index 11 i have two drugs but it only returns one drug

Comment: Check and verify the generated sql query by this `$orders = DrugRequest::where('user_id', $user_id)->with(['drugs'])->latest()->toSql();` .

Comment: @MaulikShah it returns "select * from `drug_requests` where `user_id` = ? order by `created_at` desc"

Comment: It should work. Because your relationship is perfect and query as well. Check once with your db or by removing the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the issue it was the query, i made the changes and it worked like this:

`$orders = DrugRequest::where('user_id', $user_id)->with('drugs')->latest()->get();`